# What happens within a text area field

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am curious, what happens within a text area field when a user presses enter? I remember reading someplace that "/n" is generated "behind the scenes." Is that true? If not what happens really?

Comment: It't not "behind the scenes", it's just not visible since it's a control character.

Comment: No, it's `\n`. See for yourself... http://jsfiddle.net/Yaq46/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not behind the scenes; `\n` (not `/n`) is the escape sequence for a newline. The reason you don't see it in the textarea is because the control actually renders a newline. [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/Yaq46/).